# В каком промежутке после получения апдейта из декоратора @dp.chat_join_request_handler(), бот может отправлять сообщение пользователю?

Tags: telegram, aiogram, asyncio

Возникла проблема, после подачи заявки в закрытый канал, боту прилетает апдейт через декоратор `@dp.chat_join_request_handler()`, я сохраняю id пользователя в базу данных, после чего, через некоторое время пытаюсь через бота отправить сообщение пользователю из этой базы данных, получаю ошибку: `bot can't initiate conversation with a user`. Дак вот в чем собственно вопрос: "Может ли эта проблема быть обусловлена тем, что бот должен через какое-то время взаимодействовать с пользователем, чтобы информация о нем не исчезала, так как заявка была подана давно?"

*Например:*

**1 случай)** 1 числа месяца пользователь подал заявку, бот сохранил его в бд, а 15 числа месяца бот уже не может создать соединение с пользователем, т.к заявка была подана давно.

**2 случай)** 1 числа месяца пользователь также подает заявку, бот также сохраняет его в бд, но уже через день делает рассылку через еще один день - еще одну рассылку, тем самым "задерживая" пользователя и избегая ошибки `bot can't initiate conversation with a user`

В общем - изначальная задача это рассылка по id пользователей из базы данных, сформированной при подаче заявки в закрытый канал.

Comment: Мне что-то кажется что бесконечно долго, ибо даже спустя кучу времени мне спамят какие-то черти

Comment: К слову, может юзер удалил чат с вам и заблокировал?

Comment: @oleksandrigo это исключено, потому что при получении апдейта бот не пишет пользователю, следовательно пользователь даже не знает о его существовании